# Select onde aparece nome do mês?

Tags: mysql, sql, ionic3

No momento estou desenvolvendo um `app` onde eu listo em uma tabela o mês e a soma do consumo de cada mês em `KW` como mostra no print abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

só que eu n sei como eu faria pra ao invés de listar o número do mês aparece-se o nome do mês referente ao número, no momento estou usando o seguinte comando `SQL`:

```
SELECT      ROUND(SUM(c.potencia/12))/1000  AS potencia
        ,   MONTH(c.data_criacao)
FROM        consumo c 
WHERE       c.comodo_id = :id 
GROUP BY    c.data_criacao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que para isso basta evocar o método nativo do **MySQL**, `MONTHNAME`:

```
SELECT      ROUND(SUM(c.potencia/12))/1000  AS potencia
        ,   MONTHNAME(c.data_criacao)       AS mes
FROM        consumo c 
WHERE       c.comodo_id = :id 
GROUP BY    c.data_criacao
```

Se quiser ter mais trabalho ou se for mesmo necessário:

```
SELECT      ROUND(SUM(c.potencia/12))/1000  AS potencia
        ,   CASE MONTH(c.data_criacao)
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Março'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto'
            WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro'
            WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro'
            WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro'
            ELSE 'Dezembro'
            END                             AS mes
FROM        consumo c 
WHERE       c.comodo_id = :id 
GROUP BY    c.data_criacao
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu não sabia da existência dessa função.

Comment: Se for resposta da sua pergunta, não esqueça de aceitar @AndréPaiva